# If $m^*(E)=0$, prove that $m^*(E_n)=0$ for each $n$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Define $\displaystyle m^*(E)=\inf\left\{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\ell(I_n):E\subset\bigcup
 _{n=1}^\infty I_n\right\}$.

Let $E=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n$. Suppose $m^*(E)=0$. Prove that $m^*(E_n)=0$ for every $n$.

**My attempt:**

Since $m^*(E)=0$, $E$ is a countable set. This means each of the $E_n$ is also countable and so $m^*(E_n)=0$ for all $n$.

QED

---

Is this correct?

Comment: Not at all correct. Many uncountable sets have outer measure zero, e.g. many Cantor sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$E_n \subseteq E$ for all $n$. By monotonicity, $m^*(E_n) = 0$.